# The current list is out of context?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement, monodevelop

I've created a static class which contains a `List<string>` field. For the most part all is well with this list until I try to access it within a switch statement inside one of my methods. The `List<string>` originally has a value of null but I have guaranteed it will have something in it by the time this method hits (extra check in the `if` because well... it doesn't hurt to have it!)

Field declaration:

`private static List<string> currentMenuItems;`

My methods:

```
public static string returnSelectedAttack()
{
    GameObject menu = GameObject.Find ("MenuCanvas");
    Image selector = null;

    //Get the selector image
    foreach (Image item in menu.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>())
    {
        if (item.tag.Equals ("MenuSelector")) 
        {
            selector = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (selector != null && getPosition (selector.transform.position) != null && currentMenuItems != null) 
    {
        switch (getPosition (selector.transform.position)) 
        {
        case "position1":
            return currentMenuItems (0);
            break;
        case "position2":
            return currentMenuItems (1);
            break;
        case "position3":
            return currentMenuItems (2);
            break;
        case "position4":
            return currentMenuItems (3);
            break;
        case "position5":
            return currentMenuItems (4);
            break;
        case "position6":
            return currentMenuItems (5);
            break;
        default:
            return null;
            break;
        }
    } 
    else
        return null;
}

private static string getPosition(Vector2 coordinates)
{
    try
    {
        return selectorPositions[coordinates];
    }
    catch 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For all of my `currentMenuItems` access inside the switch statement are returning the error "The name `currentMenuItems` does not exist in the current context". This is odd since 1] it's a field inside the same class and 2] it's used everywhere else inside this class without issues.

I've tried numerous different things to resolve such as instantiating the list and replacing the `switch` statement with an `if` statement but it still won't find it. How can I get my `currentMenuItems` to be in context?

Side note: I'm creating this in Unity/Monodevelop so this is using .NET2.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you'd need `currentMenuItems[0]`, not `currentMenuItems(0)`. Can you reproduce this in a [mcve] rather than just showing us parts (with a lot of extraneous code)? Are you certain you're in the same class as the declaration, for example?

Comment: When Jon Skeet speaks, all listen.

Comment: Absolutely can't believe I made a mistake like that; that'll teach me for coding late at night! Changing the (x) to [x] fixed it. Thanks for the link too Jon; still slightly starstruck you've answered one of my questions!